# Why do downloads in eMule under Wine fail with "Insufficient disk space", even when there is?

Tags: linux, wine, emule

I'm using eMule 0.70a under Wine, on a Debian-based Docker container. After some downloads end, the download bar will turn stripped green and black, and the status say "Insufficient disk space", and the downloaded file won't move to "Incoming" folder or the chosen destination folder for the category was chosen for that download.

Furthermore, the log (in the server tab) will say "file system error when moving *downloaded file name*". I'm absolutely positive there's disk space in the destination. How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eMule on Wine needs an UTF-8 set locale for moving-files-after-downloading to work. Otherwise, this problem will occur. To confirm this is your issue, you will notice this problem doesn't happen when the downloaded file name contains only ASCII characters.

You can also confirm you don't have an UTF-8 locale set by issuing `locale`. In Docker, for Debian based images, it returns *POSIX* for most LC_ items when it's unset.
The fix is to set an UTF-8 globally, or on eMule launch. To generate a locale, for example en_US, run this either at image creation or in entrypoint:

```
echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen && locale-gen && \
echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/default/locale
```

And then either set the locale globally at image creation with:

```
ENV LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Or at eMule launch with:

```
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 wine ~/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/eMule/emule.exe
```

This problem is unlikely to happen on a desktop install, which probably will already have a correctly-set locale. In desktop installs, the easier solution is to run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`.